# DNS resolving issue with Google compute engine VM (over the last 24 hours)

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Since the last 24 hours our Google compute engine has not been able to resolve hostnames via the DNS.
(NOTE: Previously our compute engine has been working without this issue for over 2 months)

For an example, if I ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) it gives an error message as

> - ping: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com): Temporary failure in name resolution*

Anyone else has experienced this before?

Comment: There may be many reasons to that. Did you made any changes to the machine ? Did you try to restart the VM ?

Comment: @Wojtek_B Yes I restarted the VM

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest way to solve this issue would be to add manually a nameserver to the `/etc/resolv.conf file`.**

This file is overwritten every time OS boots up so to make changes permament you need to add the nameserver at each boot.

This means adding this line at the end if your `/etc/rc.local` file:

`echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1" >> /etc/resolv.conf` (I've used 1.1.1.1 as an example but feel free to use any other DNS for this).

Reboot the VM to check if the new DNS is being added to `resolv.conf`. If so you can check if the service is using new DNS with `resolvectl status`; you should see something simillar:

```
ssdfdf@mvn:~$ resolvectl status
Global
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: yes
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: yes
  Current DNS Server: 169.254.169.254
         DNS Servers: 169.254.169.254
                      8.8.8.8
                      1.1.1.1
          DNS Domain: c.xxxxx.internal
                      google.internal
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
```